# Can't load CSS file (error in console log) on "localhost:3000/" in node.js?

Tags: css, node.js, http-status-code-404, pug, middleware

[image][image][image][image: enter image description he[![enter image description here]re][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W03ZG.png)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W03ZG.png)**app.js file:**

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on port 3000');
```

**index.jade file:**

```
doctype 
html
  head 
    title Home 
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/style.css')
  body
    header
      h1 Home
    footer
      p Designed By Me
```

When I load the browser at localhost:3000/, I get 404, failed to load "localhost:3000/css/style.css". Whats the problem???

**directory structure:**

root

- public

  - css

    - style.css
- app.js
- views

  - index.jade

THNX

Comment: I just recreated your app and I am getting everything to work as expected... You're linking your `css` file correctly in the `pug` file... but the `localhost:3000/style.css` is incorrect, technically it should be `localhost:3000/css/style.css` - which works for me as well... but following your exact code and structure, I am getting the expected result....

Comment: does that give us any clues to where the error might be then?

Comment: and yeh my bad I meant localhost:3000/css/style.css

Comment: there is no error in the code and structure you specified above... perhaps you're leaving something out from the example above that's causing the problem, but everything works on my end

Comment: ill take a screenshot hold on a sec

Comment: done, edited Q and added screenshots above!

Comment: are you doing `node app.js` to run your app or `node server.js`... I guess what is the difference between these two, if any? maybe you're running the wrong `server` (?) perhaps your `npm start` command is using the `server.js` instead of `app.js` file

Comment: I'm doing nodemon app.js, no code in server.js yet, thats there for later when I need to seperate my code as it gets more complicated

Comment: open that page in your browser . Then right click in click on view page source. In that check this css link. Click on that link and check it is opening or showing not found.

Comment: what happens if you just try to go to `localhost:3000/css/style.css`, are the stylesheets appearing in the browser? everything works on my end as expected...

Comment: It saids "failed to load resource: server responded with status 404". When I click it, it says "an error occurred trying to load the resource" @AJS

Comment: can you show a screenshot?

Comment: If I try go to localhost:3000/css/style.css, it says : "Cannot GET /css/style.css" @evvels1

Comment: look above for more images

Comment: can you paste src link in browser for loading css that you are getting 404

Comment: I did and message I get "Cannot GET /css/style.css", image of it above

Comment: i recreated your app here - https://github.com/goto1/test - if you clone this repo, do `npm install` then do either `node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js` or `node app.js` and then go to `localhost:3001` it will work as expected (i changed the port because something else was running on my `3000`)

Comment: when you see source after right clicking, there must be some tag to load that css like script paste that

Comment: or take screen shot of your page source

Comment: Im getting an error can't find module jade? @evvels1

Comment: added screen shot of page source above in Q @AJS

Comment: run `npm install jade --save` then do `node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js`, i guess my `package.json` didn't include the `jade` dependency... or just `node app.js` either way the server will start up

Comment: I noticed you had the pug dependancy so changed it to that in my file name and view engine, even though there the same thing?, and it works...weird...

Comment: yeah `jade` change its name to `pug` because of some naming issues but it's the same exact thing... and could be some other code causing this issue, although I am not seeing anything in your `app.js` that you're importing and could be causing some issues

Comment: Im going over mine and your version and there exactly the same, don't know why one is working and the other not..

Comment: perhaps there was an issue when you installed your dependencies? assuming you have the `package.json` file set up properly, you could technically delete your `node_modules` directory and do an `npm install` again to reinstall your modules and see if this helps, otherwise i am not sure what's going on

Comment: I tried reinstall , nothing fixed, gonna try to remake it from scratch and see what happens, is there a specific order I have to do things maybe Im not when installing packages?

Comment: yeh thats weird, remade it from scratch and it works fine,....no idea what went on..but glad its fixed..thnx for your time and help :) appreciate it

Comment: is your CSS folder is in root folder ? if yes check its permissions.

Comment: I remade the app and it works now for some reason, no idea why, its exactly the same but thnx for your time, appreciate it !

Comment: welcome!!!!!!!!!